# Como pasar un datatable como parametro?

Tags: vb.net

Buenas tengo un método que le paso o deseo pasarle dos parámetros uno un delatable con registros y el otro un nombre de tipo cadena, mi problema esta en la llamada, cuando le paso el datable va bacillo como que pierdo los registros.

La llamada que estoy haciendo:

```
Dim dt As dsdettransies.mvxINSSMensualDataTable
    CreateTabDelimatedFile(dt, "C:\TxtFiles\MyLog.txt")

mi metodo esperando los registros o el datatable lleno

    Private Sub CreateTabDelimatedFile(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal FileName As String)
            Dim DR As DataRow
            Dim ColCt As Integer
            Dim OPString As String
            Dim SW As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(FileName)
    
            'construyendo el ciclo de lectura, leyendolo
            For Each DR In dt.Rows
                OPString = ""
                For ColCt = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    If OPString <> "" Then OPString = OPString & vbTab
                    OPString = OPString & DR(ColCt)
                Next
                SW.WriteLine(OPString)
            Next
            SW.Close()
        End Sub
```

No me llega nada de registros que malo tengo en la pasada del datatable. Estoy trabajando en VB.net en VS2019 con SQL 2019

Answer (score 1):

Prueba primero declarando la variable dt como un DataTable, luego carga la variable dt con los registros de tu base de datos, y recién pasa a tu método CreateTabDelimatedFile(dt, "C:\TxtFiles\MyLog.txt").

Me comentas.

Comment: Cuando dices carga, es con el for each que tengo para llenarlo?

Answer (score 0):

En la linea `Dim dt As dsdettransies.mvxINSSMensualDataTable` tu estas definiendo la variable `dt`, pero al definirla no le estas introduciendo datos, solo esta definida, por tanto al pasarla no lleva información.